# Adding tooltip to svg's paths

Tags: javascript

I have an svg map made by paths, and I want to show a tooltip when a path is clicked and I have to do everything with JavaScript.

I am expecting that when a path is clicked a tooltip show up with information retrieved from an async function.

***This is the svg made in js***.

(regioni object and keys array is being retrieved from another file)

```js
let svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')
svg.setAttribute('version', '1.1')
svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
svg.setAttribute('x', '0px')
svg.setAttribute('y', '0px')
svg.style.width = '560.512px'
svg.style.height = '663.114px'
svg.style.display = 'block'
svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 560.512 663.114')
svg.setAttribute('xml:space', 'preserve')
let g = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g')
let defs = document.createElement('defs')
//document.body.appendChild(svg)
svg.appendChild(defs)
svg.appendChild(g)
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')
  path.setAttribute('fill', '#3E5C73')
  path.setAttribute('class', 'regione')
  path.setAttribute('data-nome-regione', 'Piemonte')
  path.setAttribute('stroke', '#3E5C73')
  path.setAttribute('stroke-width', '2')
  path.setAttribute('stroke-miterlimit', '10')
  path.setAttribute('d', 'M79.634,47.228
        c1.592-1.213,3.004-2.87,5.694-2.251c0.204,3.029,0.987,6.042-1.072,8.84c-0.295,0.402-0.527,1.177-0.337,1.551
        c0.756,1.488,1.413,3.207,2.619,4.244c2.057,1.769,3.585,3.814,4.746,6.197c0.833,1.71,2.272,2.474,4.044,2.602
        c1.946,3.362,1.325,6.248-1.105,8.909c-0.576,0.63-1.064,1.351-1.691,1.921c-1.67,1.517-2.377,3.356-2.148,5.596
        c0.057,0.557,0.113,1.228-0.133,1.682c-1.169,2.156-0.525,4.16,0.142,6.29c0.453,1.447,1.083,2.415,2.371,3.3
        c1.182,0.812,1.916,2.277,2.942,3.575c-0.413,0.701-0.824,1.4-1.225,2.081c0.125,0.337,0.144,0.698,0.331,0.843
        c1.113,0.86,1.705,1.991,1.908,3.356c0.284,1.907,1.378,3.299,2.879,4.392c1.832,1.335,2.807,3.188,3.638,5.521
        c-1.553,0.339-2.916,0.618-4.269,0.936c-1.813,0.427-2.323,1.049-2.513,2.921c-0.094,0.927-0.208,1.853-0.354,2.772
        c-0.021,0.132-0.278,0.226-0.571,0.447c-0.367-0.667-0.767-1.288-1.066-1.954c-1.39-3.094-5.974-3.94-8.284-1.53
        c-0.834,0.87-1.18,1.889-0.315,2.773c2.312,2.364,2.369,5.405,2.549,8.342c0.081,1.327,0.38,2.204,1.558,2.684
        c1.831,0.746,2.537,2.151,2.568,4.028c0.006,0.373,0.145,0.743,0.205,1.118c0.552,3.447,1.016,4.032,4.442,4.159
        c2.242,0.083,4.502-0.309,6.754-0.484c0.549-0.043,1.099-0.069,1.882-0.117
    c-0.266,2.268,0.968,3.391,2.776,3.854
        c0.155,0.314,0.32,0.488,0.306,0.646c-0.199,2.299-0.211,4.402,2.922,4.731c0.413,0.043,0.903,1.107,1.036,1.764
        c0.5,2.459,0.438,2.553,2.671,2.883c1.061,0.156,1.716,0.498,2.149,1.505c0.29,0.675,0.962,1.179,1.301,1.842
        c0.324,0.633,0.645,1.385,0.609,2.065c-0.164,3.093-0.454,6.179-0.707,9.383c-1.387,0.589-2.555,0.698-3.233-0.994
        c-0.07-0.175-0.141-0.366-0.264-0.502c-1.608-1.792-4.093-2.314-5.837-3.987c-0.316-0.303-1.868,0.487-2.725,0.986
        c-1.47,0.856-2.987,1.712-2.144,3.979c0.37,0.994-0.638,1.632-1.478,1.71c-1.943,0.18-3.102,1.242-3.537,2.363
        c-2.021,0.749-3.538,1.343-5.081,1.865c-0.496,0.168-1.084,0.283-1.582,0.184c-1.663-0.329-3.309-0.752-4.955-1.166
        c-2.946-0.741-4.175-0.313-6.053,2.164c-0.276,0.364-0.524,0.75-0.925,1.328c-0.833-0.634-1.556-1.198-2.294-1.742
        c-2.582-1.903-5.068-1.311-6.084,1.654c-0.621,1.812-1.047,3.638-2.703,4.834c-0.073,0.053-0.165,0.155-0.159,0.228
        c0.196,2.65-1.954,3.761-3.372,5.432c-1.425,1.679-1.364,3.863-0.762,5.957c0.749,2.607,0.568,2.919-2.038,3.366
        c-2.831,0.485-2.905,0.556-3.348,3.238c-2.54,0.267-5.022,0.536-7.369-1.088c-0.667-0.461-1.922-0.071-3.174-0.071
        c0.191-0.896,0.376-1.59,0.481-2.296c0.227-1.523-0.5-2.535-1.814-1.955c-2.725,1.202-5.971,0.662-8.4,2.77
        c-1.316,1.142-3.653,0.981-5.164-0.067c-0.371-0.257-0.801-0.773-1.116-0.713c-3.477,0.671-5.453-1.607-7.534-3.882
        c-1.551,0.528-2.841,0.293-4.15-0.849c-0.677-0.591-2.019-0.42-3.355-0.642c-0.092-2.207-1.7-4.029-3.168-5.93
        c-0.23-0.298-0.436-0.617-0.624-0.944c-1.659-2.882-1.58-3.35,1.196-5.628c-0.652-0.822-1.321-1.658-1.981-2.499
        c-0.577-0.735-1.219-1.432-1.698-2.227c-0.696-1.154-0.457-2.057,0.757-2.86c2.423-1.601,3.275-3.686,3.074-6.736
        c-0.075-1.136,0.66-1.743,1.68-1.897c0.64-0.097,1.339,0.178,1.976,0.073c0.596-0.099,1.483-0.354,1.634-0.765
        c0.216-0.587-0.116-1.379-0.23-2.08c-0.012-0.076-0.126-0.136-0.194-0.202c-1.771-1.729-2.685-3.613-1.877-6.231
        c0.21-0.681-0.633-2.226-1.357-2.543c-1.398-0.612-2.726-2.04-4.688-0.716c-1.208,0.815-2.703,0.062-3.758-1.04
        c-0.586-0.612-1.258-1.169-1.722-1.863c-0.49-0.733-0.936-1.567-1.114-2.417c-0.21-1.003-0.032-2.081-0.162-3.108
        c-0.319-2.526-0.793-2.92-3.538-3.064c-0.207-0.641-0.393-1.352-0.666-2.028c-0.279-0.69-0.643-1.345-1.024-2.127
        c1.194-1.017,2.161-2.046,3.971-1.75c0.656,0.107,1.463-0.707,2.31-1.16c0.525,0.255,1.109,0.551,1.703,0.825
        c1.941,0.897,2.261,0.789,3.678-1.021c0.265-0.339,0.668-0.597,1.053-0.808c0.406-0.222,1.049-0.213,1.274-0.529
        c1.398-1.959,3.086-2.861,5.639-3.029c2.36-0.155,4.041-3.682,3.167-5.955c-0.575-1.495-0.43-2.538,0.808-3.475
        c0.074-0.056,0.135-0.134,0.194-0.208c2.402-3.021,2.371-3.256-0.707-5.732c-0.138-0.111-0.211-0.301-0.61-0.891
        c1.742,0.922,2.702,0.145,3.897-0.578c1.612-0.976,3.645-2.074,5.352-1.874c2.241,0.261,3.131-0.933,4.17-2.177
        c2.138-2.559,2.336-2.656,5.38-1.236c0.425,0.198,0.861,0.469,1.309,0.507c2.612,0.225,5.251,0.695,7.838,0.506
        c3.869-0.283,6.597-2.587,8.287-6.032c0.306-0.623,0.465-1.606,0.185-2.173c-0.727-1.476-0.466-2.701,0.627-3.944
        c-0.737-1.116-1.409-2.134-2.081-3.151c-1.147-1.736-1.577-3.579-1.064-5.655c0.786-3.179,1.482-6.38,2.258-9.753
        c0.564-0.04,1.194-0.098,1.826-0.128c2.655-0.128,4.455-1.762,4.585-4.407c0.078-1.575,0.43-2.572,2.139-3.174
        c4.881-1.721,5.832-6.611,2.152-10.334c-0.197-0.199-0.354-0.439-0.541-0.674c0.393-1.074,1.015-1.797,2.265-1.773
        c1.487,0.029,2.394-0.792,3.204-1.986c0.623-0.917,1.501-1.724,2.415-2.37C80.403,50.028,80.435,50.073,79.634,47.228z')
  path.style.transition = 'all 200ms ease-in-out'
  path.style.position = 'relative'

  g.appendChild(path)

  path.onclick = async() => {
    let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path')
    paths.forEach((path) => {
      path.classList.remove('selected')
      path.style.fill = '#3E5C73'
    })
    path.setAttribute('id', 'tooltip')
    path.setAttribute('class', 'selected')
    path.style.fill = 'white'
  }
}
```

***This is the rendered html from above javascript***

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="560.512px" height="663.114px" viewBox="0 0 
       560.512 663.114" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
    </defs>
     <g>
      <path fill="#3E5C73"  class="regione" data-nome-regione="Piemonte" stroke="#3E5C73" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M79.634,47.228
        c1.592-1.213,3.004-2.87,5.694-2.251c0.204,3.029,0.987,6.042-1.072,8.84c-0.295,0.402-0.527,1.177-0.337,1.551
        c0.756,1.488,1.413,3.207,2.619,4.244c2.057,1.769,3.585,3.814,4.746,6.197c0.833,1.71,2.272,2.474,4.044,2.602
        c1.946,3.362,1.325,6.248-1.105,8.909c-0.576,0.63-1.064,1.351-1.691,1.921c-1.67,1.517-2.377,3.356-2.148,5.596
        c0.057,0.557,0.113,1.228-0.133,1.682c-1.169,2.156-0.525,4.16,0.142,6.29c0.453,1.447,1.083,2.415,2.371,3.3
        c1.182,0.812,1.916,2.277,2.942,3.575c-0.413,0.701-0.824,1.4-1.225,2.081c0.125,0.337,0.144,0.698,0.331,0.843
        c1.113,0.86,1.705,1.991,1.908,3.356c0.284,1.907,1.378,3.299,2.879,4.392c1.832,1.335,2.807,3.188,3.638,5.521
        c-1.553,0.339-2.916,0.618-4.269,0.936c-1.813,0.427-2.323,1.049-2.513,2.921c-0.094,0.927-0.208,1.853-0.354,2.772
        c-0.021,0.132-0.278,0.226-0.571,0.447c-0.367-0.667-0.767-1.288-1.066-1.954c-1.39-3.094-5.974-3.94-8.284-1.53
        c-0.834,0.87-1.18,1.889-0.315,2.773c2.312,2.364,2.369,5.405,2.549,8.342c0.081,1.327,0.38,2.204,1.558,2.684
        c1.831,0.746,2.537,2.151,2.568,4.028c0.006,0.373,0.145,0.743,0.205,1.118c0.552,3.447,1.016,4.032,4.442,4.159
        c2.242,0.083,4.502-0.309,6.754-0.484c0.549-0.043,1.099-0.069,1.882-0.117c-0.266,2.268,0.968,3.391,2.776,3.854
        c0.155,0.314,0.32,0.488,0.306,0.646c-0.199,2.299-0.211,4.402,2.922,4.731c0.413,0.043,0.903,1.107,1.036,1.764
        c0.5,2.459,0.438,2.553,2.671,2.883c1.061,0.156,1.716,0.498,2.149,1.505c0.29,0.675,0.962,1.179,1.301,1.842
        c0.324,0.633,0.645,1.385,0.609,2.065c-0.164,3.093-0.454,6.179-0.707,9.383c-1.387,0.589-2.555,0.698-3.233-0.994
        c-0.07-0.175-0.141-0.366-0.264-0.502c-1.608-1.792-4.093-2.314-5.837-3.987c-0.316-0.303-1.868,0.487-2.725,0.986
        c-1.47,0.856-2.987,1.712-2.144,3.979c0.37,0.994-0.638,1.632-1.478,1.71c-1.943,0.18-3.102,1.242-3.537,2.363
        c-2.021,0.749-3.538,1.343-5.081,1.865c-0.496,0.168-1.084,0.283-1.582,0.184c-1.663-0.329-3.309-0.752-4.955-1.166
        c-2.946-0.741-4.175-0.313-6.053,2.164c-0.276,0.364-0.524,0.75-0.925,1.328c-0.833-0.634-1.556-1.198-2.294-1.742
        c-2.582-1.903-5.068-1.311-6.084,1.654c-0.621,1.812-1.047,3.638-2.703,4.834c-0.073,0.053-0.165,0.155-0.159,0.228
        c0.196,2.65-1.954,3.761-3.372,5.432c-1.425,1.679-1.364,3.863-0.762,5.957c0.749,2.607,0.568,2.919-2.038,3.366
        c-2.831,0.485-2.905,0.556-3.348,3.238c-2.54,0.267-5.022,0.536-7.369-1.088c-0.667-0.461-1.922-0.071-3.174-0.071
        c0.191-0.896,0.376-1.59,0.481-2.296c0.227-1.523-0.5-2.535-1.814-1.955c-2.725,1.202-5.971,0.662-8.4,2.77
        c-1.316,1.142-3.653,0.981-5.164-0.067c-0.371-0.257-0.801-0.773-1.116-0.713c-3.477,0.671-5.453-1.607-7.534-3.882
        c-1.551,0.528-2.841,0.293-4.15-0.849c-0.677-0.591-2.019-0.42-3.355-0.642c-0.092-2.207-1.7-4.029-3.168-5.93
        c-0.23-0.298-0.436-0.617-0.624-0.944c-1.659-2.882-1.58-3.35,1.196-5.628c-0.652-0.822-1.321-1.658-1.981-2.499
        c-0.577-0.735-1.219-1.432-1.698-2.227c-0.696-1.154-0.457-2.057,0.757-2.86c2.423-1.601,3.275-3.686,3.074-6.736
        c-0.075-1.136,0.66-1.743,1.68-1.897c0.64-0.097,1.339,0.178,1.976,0.073c0.596-0.099,1.483-0.354,1.634-0.765
        c0.216-0.587-0.116-1.379-0.23-2.08c-0.012-0.076-0.126-0.136-0.194-0.202c-1.771-1.729-2.685-3.613-1.877-6.231
        c0.21-0.681-0.633-2.226-1.357-2.543c-1.398-0.612-2.726-2.04-4.688-0.716c-1.208,0.815-2.703,0.062-3.758-1.04
        c-0.586-0.612-1.258-1.169-1.722-1.863c-0.49-0.733-0.936-1.567-1.114-2.417c-0.21-1.003-0.032-2.081-0.162-3.108
        c-0.319-2.526-0.793-2.92-3.538-3.064c-0.207-0.641-0.393-1.352-0.666-2.028c-0.279-0.69-0.643-1.345-1.024-2.127
        c1.194-1.017,2.161-2.046,3.971-1.75c0.656,0.107,1.463-0.707,2.31-1.16c0.525,0.255,1.109,0.551,1.703,0.825
        c1.941,0.897,2.261,0.789,3.678-1.021c0.265-0.339,0.668-0.597,1.053-0.808c0.406-0.222,1.049-0.213,1.274-0.529
        c1.398-1.959,3.086-2.861,5.639-3.029c2.36-0.155,4.041-3.682,3.167-5.955c-0.575-1.495-0.43-2.538,0.808-3.475
        c0.074-0.056,0.135-0.134,0.194-0.208c2.402-3.021,2.371-3.256-0.707-5.732c-0.138-0.111-0.211-0.301-0.61-0.891
        c1.742,0.922,2.702,0.145,3.897-0.578c1.612-0.976,3.645-2.074,5.352-1.874c2.241,0.261,3.131-0.933,4.17-2.177
        c2.138-2.559,2.336-2.656,5.38-1.236c0.425,0.198,0.861,0.469,1.309,0.507c2.612,0.225,5.251,0.695,7.838,0.506
        c3.869-0.283,6.597-2.587,8.287-6.032c0.306-0.623,0.465-1.606,0.185-2.173c-0.727-1.476-0.466-2.701,0.627-3.944
        c-0.737-1.116-1.409-2.134-2.081-3.151c-1.147-1.736-1.577-3.579-1.064-5.655c0.786-3.179,1.482-6.38,2.258-9.753
        c0.564-0.04,1.194-0.098,1.826-0.128c2.655-0.128,4.455-1.762,4.585-4.407c0.078-1.575,0.43-2.572,2.139-3.174
        c4.881-1.721,5.832-6.611,2.152-10.334c-0.197-0.199-0.354-0.439-0.541-0.674c0.393-1.074,1.015-1.797,2.265-1.773
        c1.487,0.029,2.394-0.792,3.204-1.986c0.623-0.917,1.501-1.724,2.415-2.37C80.403,50.028,80.435,50.073,79.634,47.228z"/>
    
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Please include a [mre] (you can hard-code things like `regioni` and `keys` at the top of the file for the sake of an example), and explain what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I added just aportion of the map because stackoverflow don't let me add all the lines of code

Comment: From the JavaScript, `keys` is not defined, as I imagine you anticipated. Would it be possible to provide a snippet of the relevant variable in order that the snippet generates a (representative, small) map? That way we may be able to offer better advice.

Comment: @DavidThomas I edited the post and add a portion of the map

Comment: And yet I'm still seeing: `ReferenceError: keys is not defined`?

Comment: did you try to just add a click event listener to the `path` element? if you for example give an id to the path as `piemonte`, it would be as easy as `document.querySelector('#piemonte path').addEventListener('click',(event)=>{/*event handler*/})`

Comment: otherwise if you really just wanted to add the tooltip, it would enough to add the `<title>` element as a child of the `<path>` (not to be confused with the title attribute that doesn't work in this scenario)

Comment: @DavidThomas the second snippet is a part of the map and if copy that code inside an empty body it should work

Comment: @DiegoD all paths are created in a for loop as you can see in the first snippet, so if you make the query like you said it would work only for that path, for allthe others?

Comment: But as you point out "*all paths are created in a for loop*," which is where the tool-tips should be created, which is why I wanted to see a functional sample of your JavaScript that actually works.

Comment: @DavidThomas i tried but there is an aerrror i cannot find but you can just copy in your editor the path from the second snippet

Answer (score 1):

Another Edit: A "title" element nested within a "path" element does provide tooltip functionality.  I wonder if tooltip functionality isn't exactly what we are seeking for this scenario, given the tooltip hover delay?

Edit:  I wrote here that "Title element is not valid within SVG even if Chrome does that for Googlers" which was pointed out as incorrect.  I meant title does not work within PATH, and that is IME, in my experience, not according to any spec, just according to a lack of it working and a lack of solutions while Ducking for solutions.  Edit: Codepen below in a comment from herrstrietzel demonstrates my experience to have been wrong. ....my title does in fact generate a tooltip.

I did the following for SVG PATHs filled with black, PATHs having id for what the ~tooltip should say.

onmouseover and onmouseout frequently should use setTimeout with slight delay to mimic an actual hover rather than a mouse moving across an element,but in my case I didn't need that, so the hover-ish delay is omitted here.

```
function path_hover(p) {
   const t = p.target;
   console.log('mouseover on ' + t.id);
    
    const h = document.createElement("span");
    h.id = "title_" + t.id;
    h.title = t.id;
    h.style.position = 'absolute';
    h.style.left = p.pageX + "px";
    h.style.top = p.pageY + "px";
    h.value = t.id;
    h.zindex = 100;
    h.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
    h.style.color = "#ffffff";
    h.style.paddingTop = '2px';
    h.style.paddingBottom = '2px';
    h.style.paddingLeft = '10px';
    h.style.paddingRight = '10px';
    h.innerText = t.id;
    window.document.body.appendChild(h);     
}

function path_unhover(p) {
   const t = p.target;
   console.log('mouse out from ' + t.id);
   const h = "title_" + t.id;
   const hp = document.getElementById(h);
   window.document.body.removeChild(hp);
}


document.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => { 
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') { 

         const paths = document.getElementsByTagName("path");
         if (paths) {
             for (let p of paths) {
                 p.addEventListener("mouseover", path_hover);
                 p.addEventListener("mouseout", path_unhover);
                
             }
         }

    }
});
```

While you're at it, inside let p of paths, you can of course assign a click too...

```
             p.addEventListener("click", path_clicked);
```

...along with a function path_clicked

Comment: Oops. my tooltips don't require a click.  But everything's here for you to revise as needed to show the ~tooltip span in a function path_clicked.    If you need to show a tooltip that isn't a valid element id, alter to use some PATH element data attribute of your choosing instead.

Comment: `<title>` elements are perfectly valid in svg. See ["SVG specs: 5.8. The ‘desc’ and ‘title’ elements"](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements)

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. Title is fine for SVG.  Title does not seem to work within/for PATH elements.  Will edit above to correct that and word it as "IME" rather that invalid

Comment: Ah, I think by inside you mean the title attribute? That is indeed not supported or won't have any effect. You can wrap a title element within a closing `</path>` tag and it works. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/xxBKZvm?editors=1010)

Comment: Looking at your codepen, you are again correct.  I could swear I did that and it didn't work, but clearly, on your codepen, the title element nested within a path element does work for showing a tooltip.  I wonder why I (and other folks on the interweb) have had, or thought we had, no luck with that. I wonder I/we just didn't hover long enough for the tooltip delay.  That could be all my issue was, effectively impatience, but if so, that potentially raises a question of whether tooltip is a good approach for adding ~tooltips to SVG PATHs.

Comment: I'd say a `<title>` element is rather a simplistic tooltip approach (no styling options etc.) A manual approach as you suggested is probably the better option as you could specify offsets, styling and also whether it should appear on click or on mouseover.